# How to use Grails Spring Security Plugin to require logging in before access an action?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I know that I can use annotation or Request mapping to restrict access to an ACTION by some specific ROLES. But now I have a different circumstance.

My scenario is: every user of my site can create posts, and they can make their own post **public, private, or only share to some other users**. I implement sharing post by a database table PERMISSION, which specify if a user have the right to view a post or not.

The problem arises here is that when a customer access a post through a direct link, how can I determine he/she have the privilege to view it? There's 3 circumstances:

> 1. The post is public, so it can be viewed by anyone (include not-login
>      user)
> 2. The post is private, so only the login-owner can view it
> 3. The post is sharing, it means only the login-user that is shared and the
>      owner can view it.

I want to process like this:

> 1. If the requested post is public: ok.
> 2. If the requested post is private/sharing: I want to redirect
>      the customer to the login page; after
>      logging in, the user will be re-direct
>      to the page he wants to see.

The problem here is that I can redirect the user to login controller/ auth action, but after that I don't know how to redirect it back. The link to every post is different by post_id, so I can't use `SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl`

Could anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a quick workaround for this problem:

1. If the user is logged in: check the user's privilege, and return the appropriate result.
2. If the user is not logged in: At view action, set the post_id by:

   session.post_id = 8
3. Redirect the user to the Login Controller/ Auth action.
4. At checkrole action(which is my `grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl` in Config.groovy), if session.post_id exists, use it to build the link for re-directing to the view action. Before redirecting, clear the session.post_id.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about grails, but spring security has a `spring-security-redirect` parameter which can be used to redirect the user to the specified url on successful authentication.

Comment: thanks, it does have that parameter. But the thing here is that the link isn't fixed, and I must create the link by post_id.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add your own filter that will be executed before the action is called and do the verification of the post permissions there. You can find more information about Grails Filters [here](http://www.grails.org/Filters).

Comment: but after re-directing, how can I get back to the previous action?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Grails Spring Security ACL plugin? I don't know it very well, but it's designed to restrict access to particular instances:

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl

Comment: thanks for the recommedation. Actually, I have come too far to return and utilize another plugin. Maybe I'll have a look on it for later project